# How to use F# 4.7 on Mac?

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

With the latest VS for mac installed (8.5 preview) and the latest net core sdk (3.1.200) F# 4.7 should be supported. When I run the dotnet fsi, indeed language features are supported and the FSI shows F# 4.7 as the F# version.

In VS for mac, in the preferences settings the exact command: /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet fsi is the path to the F# compiler.

However, when creating a new fix file and trying F# language features, it doesn’t work and the FSI in VS for mac doesn’t compile the code. Also, the FI for mac doesn’t show with F# version is used.

So, it is possible to use F# 4.7 features in Visual Studio for Mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The disappointing answer is, you can't. I have raised this issue months ago. But still no luck.