# How to compile F# in any version on mac?

Tags: macos, f#

(I am aware of the existing [stack overflow question How to use F# 4.7 on Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60803110/how-to-use-f-4-7-on-mac) that is very similar, but not identical, and that have no solution yet)

On my mac (catalina 10.15.7) I installed the .NET core via this [link](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core) with no issues.

The command

```
dotnet --help
```

correctly returns the help.

When trying to initialise a new project, it fails with:

```
$ dotnet new –lang f#
Getting ready...
Couldn't find an installed template that matches the input, searching online for one that does...
No templates found matching: '–lang'.

$ dotnet new --lang "f#"
Invalid input switch:
  --lang
  f#
Run dotnet new --help for usage information.
See https://aka.ms/dotnet-install-templates to learn how to install additional template packs.
```

So how do I start a project or run a F# file on mac? Is there any up to date blog post providing a tutorial for installing an F# compiler?

----- EDIT -----

The command `dotnet new` returns:

```
$ dotnet new
Templates                                         Short Name          Language          Tags                  
--------------------------------------------      --------------      ------------      ----------------------
Console Application                               console             [C#], F#, VB      Common/Console        
Class library                                     classlib            [C#], F#, VB      Common/Library        
Worker Service                                    worker              [C#], F#          Common/Worker/Web     
Unit Test Project                                 mstest              [C#], F#, VB      Test/MSTest           
NUnit 3 Test Project                              nunit               [C#], F#, VB      Test/NUnit            
NUnit 3 Test Item                                 nunit-test          [C#], F#, VB      Test/NUnit            
xUnit Test Project                                xunit               [C#], F#, VB      Test/xUnit            
Razor Component                                   razorcomponent      [C#]              Web/ASP.NET           
Razor Page                                        page                [C#]              Web/ASP.NET           
MVC ViewImports                                   viewimports         [C#]              Web/ASP.NET           
MVC ViewStart                                     viewstart           [C#]              Web/ASP.NET           
Blazor Server App                                 blazorserver        [C#]              Web/Blazor            
Blazor WebAssembly App                            blazorwasm          [C#]              Web/Blazor/WebAssembly
ASP.NET Core Empty                                web                 [C#], F#          Web/Empty             
ASP.NET Core Web App (Model-View-Controller)      mvc                 [C#], F#          Web/MVC               
ASP.NET Core Web App                              webapp              [C#]              Web/MVC/Razor Pages   
ASP.NET Core with Angular                         angular             [C#]              Web/MVC/SPA           
ASP.NET Core with React.js                        react               [C#]              Web/MVC/SPA           
ASP.NET Core with React.js and Redux              reactredux          [C#]              Web/MVC/SPA           
Razor Class Library                               razorclasslib       [C#]              Web/Razor/Library     
ASP.NET Core Web API                              webapi              [C#], F#          Web/WebAPI            
ASP.NET Core gRPC Service                         grpc                [C#]              Web/gRPC              
dotnet gitignore file                             gitignore                             Config                
global.json file                                  globaljson                            Config                
NuGet Config                                      nugetconfig                           Config                
Dotnet local tool manifest file                   tool-manifest                         Config                
Web Config                                        webconfig                             Config                
Solution File                                     sln                                   Solution              
Protocol Buffer File                              proto                                 Web/gRPC              

Examples:
    dotnet new mvc --auth Individual
    dotnet new web 
    dotnet new --help
    dotnet new classlib --help
```

Comment: This shows that the F# templates are already available and `dotnet new -lang f#` should work. Make sure you have no typo. On my machine typing `dotnet new -lang f#` works but pasting what *you* typed doesn't. Did you copy that command line from a web page perhaps?

Comment: It's the dash - somehow, you copied a glyph that looks like a dash but isn't. *Type* the commands instead of copying them

Comment: Lots of text editors in web sites, wikis and blogs replace minus with dashes, quotes with typography quotes, to make text look better. Word processors like Word or Google Docs do the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Watch out for formatting when copying from web sites**

The dash in the question's `–lang` isn't the minus character `-`, it's an [en dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#En_dash). I suspect you copied the command from a web site that replaced the minus character with an en dash. This is similar to sites replacing `"` or `'` with typography quotes.

Type the command directly instead of pasting it.

**Original Answer**

`new` has no `--lang` option. Try `-lang` or `--language` to list all available templates for a language. To specify `f#` type `f#` eg :

```
> dotnet new -lang f#
These templates matched your input: language='f#'.

Templates                       Short Name      Language      Tags
--------------------------      ----------      --------      -----------------
Console Application             console         F#            Common/Console
Class library                   classlib        F#            Common/Library
Worker Service                  worker          F#            Common/Worker/Web
Unit Test Project               mstest          F#            Test/MSTest
NUnit 3 Test Project            nunit           F#            Test/NUnit
NUnit 3 Test Item               nunit-test      F#            Test/NUnit
xUnit Test Project              xunit           F#            Test/xUnit
ASP.NET Core Empty              web             F#            Web/Empty
ASP.NET Core Web App (M...      mvc             F#            Web/MVC
ASP.NET Core Web API            webapi          F#            Web/WebAPI
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that too, as in the posted example. To no avail. Do I have to install some dotnet plugin to work with f# or is there something missing in the installation?

Comment: @SeF tried what? I already posted the results that show this works. You don't need to install anything special. What does `dotnet new` alone show on your machine? How did you install the .NET SDK ?

Comment: I tried this one `dotnet new -lang f#`. And it does not work as shown in the question. To install I followed the link in the question. I also edited the question with the result of `dotnet new `.

Comment: How did you install the SDK? What does `dotnet new` alone show? `dotnet --version`? `dotnet --list-sdks` ?

Comment: It was indeed a formatting issue! Thanks!